# Type inference of differently scoped variables

Tags: typescript, tsc

Consider the code below (running in TypeScript 3.2.2):

```
const status: 'successful' | 'failed' = 'successful';

function test(): typeof status {
  const status = 'hello';

  return 'successful';
}
```

This doesn't compile since the return type of `test` and its signature do not match:

```
error TS2322: Type '"successful"' is not assignable to type 'IResult<"hello">'.
```

For some reason the `status` definition *inside* the function is being used to determine the return type.

This doesn't happen when using `var`; this code:

```
function test(): typeof status {
  var status = 'hello'; // notice the var here

  return 'successful';
}
```

produces the expected return type of `'successful' | 'failed'`.

Using `let`:

```
function test(): typeof status {
  let status = 'hello'; // notice the let here

  return 'successful';
}
```

This compiles but with the effect that the return type is `string`, the inner definition is being used again.

I expected `tsc` to use the `status` which is defined most high up in scopes to evaluate its return type in both cases, regardless of what declarations exist inside `test`. **Why is the behaviour as observed above?** This should be related to how `tsc` decides which variables to use for type inference.

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 12 cases here:
`(const, let, var) * (global, local) * (explicit string union, inferred string)`

TL;DR

#### Simple approach:

- if you specify type explicitly and in the outer scope - result is always the same: union of `"ok" | "no"`.

#### Gotcha:

- because inner `let` and `const` ARE available for `typeof` at return position, they shadow outer declaration ..
- inner `var` is not available for `typeof` at return type position (for whatever reason)

#### Add extra confusion:

- if you try to infer: `let` and `var` will consider type to be `string`, and `const` will type to exact [immutable original] value.

---

#### List of cases for reference:

```
// Infer, Inner
function test_inner_let(): typeof status01 { // type is string
  let status01 = 'ok'; // let is mutable, so type is only string
  return 'lol';
}
function test_inner_const(): typeof status02 { // type is 'ok'
  const status02 = 'ok'; // const allows to specify type to exact 'ok'
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'ok'
}
function test_inner_var(): typeof status03 { // type is any, TS warning: status03 not found
  var status03 = 'ok'; // var is mutable, so type is string
  return 'lol';
}

// Explicit, Inner
function test_inner_let_t(): typeof status11 { // type is union 'ok'|'no'
  let status11: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'ok'|'no'
}
function test_inner_const_t(): typeof status12 { // type is union 'ok'|'no'
  const status12: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'ok'|'no'
}
function test_inner_var_t(): typeof status13 { // type is any, TS warning: status13 not found
  var status13: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
  return 'lol';
}

// Explicit, Outer - everything works the same
let status21: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
function test_outer_let_t(): typeof status21 { // type is union 'ok'|'no'
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'ok'|'no'
}
const status22: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
function test_outer_const_t(): typeof status22 { // type is union 'ok'|'no'
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'ok'|'no'
}
var status23: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
function test_outer_var_t(): typeof status23 { // type is union 'ok'|'no'
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'ok'|'no'
}

// Infer, Outer
let status31 = 'ok'; // type is string
function test_outer_let(): typeof status31 { // type is string
  return 'lol';
}
const status32 = 'ok'; // const allows to specify type to exact 'ok'
function test_outer_const(): typeof status32 { // type is 'ok'
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'ok'
}
var status33 = 'ok'; // var is mutable, so type is string
function test_outer_var(): typeof status33 { // type is string
  return 'lol';
}

// (Explicit, Outer const) + (Implicit, Inner)
const status41: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
function test_combo_let(): typeof status41 { // type is string, inner let took preference
  let status41 = 'ok';
  return 'lol';
}
const status42: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
function test_combo_const(): typeof status42 { // type is 'sorry', inner const took preference
  const status42 = 'sorry';
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'sorry'
}
const status43: 'ok' | 'no' = 'ok';
function test_combo_var(): typeof status43 { // type is union 'ok'|'no', var is not bubling up
  var status = 'whatever';
  return 'lol'; // error, 'lol' is not assignable to 'ok'|'no'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer - easily understandable.

Comment: i updated the answer with combo case when inner shadows outer.